# Monitor uSWGI via Nagios: invalid socket

Tags: nagios, uwsgi, socket

I'm trying to monitor uSWGI via Nagios, but according to uWSGI I have specified an invalid socket.

The socket path I got from the JSON config file which also says `chmod-socket: 666` so I have a hunch that the problem is permission based.
The socket file is owned by `www-data` who I don't want to tinker with, so any other ways?

```
uwsgi --socket=/tmp/app.sock --nagios
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
UWSGI UNKNOWN: you have specified an invalid socket

ls -l /tmp/app.sock
srw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 0 2012-10-26 17:00 /tmp/app.sock
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which uWSGI version ? the "detected binary path" message should not appear, so you may be using some older release with some kind of bug.

Comment: `uwsgi --version` says `uWSGI 1.0.4`. `apt-cache show uwsgi` says `Version: 0.9.8.1-1` on this Ubuntu 11.10. I guess I should upgrade manually.

Comment: After I upgraded to *Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS* it doesn't show *detected binary path*